# Binding/Modeling to specific character in string in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

I have data in my controller that looks like this:
`$scope.myString = "00011"`
Is there a way I can model checkboxes to each character in the string, something like below?

`<input type="checkbox" ng-model="myString.charAt(0)" ng-checked="'1'">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="myString.charAt(1)" ng-checked="'1'">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="myString.charAt(2)" ng-checked="'1'">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="myString.charAt(3)" ng-checked="'1'">`

End result, I'd like `myString` to hold a string of the 1's and 0's I've checked. My above example does not work but shows I have made an attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this , please refer below snippet.

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope) {


$scope.myString = "00011";

$scope.checkBoxModel =  Array.from($scope.myString);


$scope.check = function(){
  $scope.myString = $scope.checkBoxModel.join("");
console.log( $scope.myString);
}

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Todo</h2>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-true-value=1 ng-false-value=0 ng-change="check()" ng-model="checkBoxModel[0]">
<input type="checkbox" ng-true-value=1 ng-false-value=0 ng-change="check()"  ng-model="checkBoxModel[1]">
<input type="checkbox" ng-true-value=1 ng-false-value=0 ng-change="check()" ng-model="checkBoxModel[2]">
<input type="checkbox" ng-true-value=1 ng-false-value=0 ng-change="check()"  ng-model="checkBoxModel[3]">
 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked great in my solution, Just a note, in my application I did not require the `change()` function As I just converted to a string on a submit to the server.

Answer (score -1):

We can not do this directly without an intermediate manipulations

```
        $scope.myString = "00111";


        $scope.booArr = [];

$scope.stringToValue($scope.myString);


        $scope.stringToValue = function(convertString){
            var len = convertString.length;
            for(var i=0; i<len; i++)
            {
                if($scope.myString.chatAt(i) == '0')
                {
                    $scope.booArr[i] = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    $scope.booArr[i] = true;
                }
            }
        };

        $scope.valueToString = function(){
            var len = $scope.booArr.length;

            var outputString = '';

            for(var i=0; i<len; i++) {
                if ($scope.booArr[i]) {
                    outputString = outputString + '1';
                }
                else {
                    outputString = outputString + '0';
                }
            }
            $scope.myString = outputString;

        };
```

Now in the HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-repeat="item in boolArr" ng-model="item" ng-change="valueToString()">
```